# React http-proxy-middleware proxy not working

Tags: reactjs, proxy, http-proxy, http-proxy-middleware

Hi I been trying the proxy solution to avoid the cors problems in myapp but it doesn't seem to work, i restarted my machine so many times and that made no difference. Basically myapp using fetchApi to call another domain (localhost:8080) which is a SpringBoot application endpoint. I added in package.json "proxy": "http://localhost:8080/" but the api still return calls with localhost:3000 and i tried setupProxy.js but i faced same issue....Am i missing anything else ! any help would be appreciated...

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    "/oauth",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "http://localhost:8080",
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false,
      logLevel: "debug",
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. In `setupProxy.js` I have something similar to the above and get the following error: `[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api from localhost:3000 to https://localhost:8080 (DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)`

Comment: Just wondering how you managed to resolve this?  Having the same issue.  Thank you

Comment: @robster I have added some cors codes in my spring boot application to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `{}` on `createProxyMiddleware` and it started working.
Thanks